# Pauli matrices in spherical coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-elements

In my work I currently have to work with the following partition function $Z\propto e^{\vec{h}.\vec{\sigma}}$ where $\vec{\sigma}$ are pauli matrices and $h$ is some vector. So far I've been using cartesian coordinates but in the problem spherical coordinates are much more appropriate.

My question is: can I write the dot product in spherical coordinates using some sort of $\sigma_r,\sigma_{\phi},\sigma_{\theta}$ matrices?

I couldn't find anything like that (and I searched...), maybe because of the problem of defining division of matrices. Thanks for your future answers ;)

Comment: Have you studied the [Pauli vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Pauli_vector)?

Comment: I think this question needs more descriptive tags.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I am not looking for some simple rotation of the Pauli vector but a way to describe the Pauli vector in spherical coordinates so that the inner product would depend only $|h|$, $\sigma^2$ and the angle in between. The difficulty is in dealing with matrices. Maybe I 'm not explaining correctly, if so please tell me

Comment: @ja72 I agree, you have any suggestion? I could find any better tags but I'm a noobie here ;)

Comment: You should be able to "reverse engineer" them. Take your dot product, with h in spherical coordinates, and see what combinations of the pauli matrices the various hats in h combine with. This is related to writing gamma matrices in spherical (or generalized) coordinates as well, a lot of older GR literature uses gamma matrices in this fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This paper

https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/14/8/1684

has the answer you really need. Straight-up expressions for all three Pauli matrices in spherical (and cylindrical) coordinates!

Comment: Wow, took 6 years but finally the answer I was looking for! Thank you! I find it curious but maybe unlikely that this was found only last year...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why division of matrices would be useful, or unavailable, since these matrices are all easily invertible, but you have implicitly answered your own question but failed to recognize the answer. It is all in the definition of the [Pauli vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Pauli_vector).

Analyze your vector $\vec{h}\equiv h \hat{r}$. It then follows that 
the scalar product 
$$
\vec{h} \cdot \vec {\sigma} = h ~\hat{r}\cdot  \vec {\sigma}  \equiv h ~\sigma_r ,
$$
is a 2x2 traceless hermitian matrix, where, significantly,
$$
\sigma_r ^2=1\!\!1 ~.
$$
The eigenvalues of this matrix are $\pm$1, and the obvious eigenvectors are in the WP article cited. (Had you chosen $\vec h$ aligned along the $\hat z$-axis, you'd have just $\sigma_r=\sigma_z$.)

The fundamental illusion that the hermitian matrix exponential you wrote (for real *h*) is a separate function collapses, as it is revealed to be just the sum of its even and odd parts, a *linear function* of $\sigma_r$,
$$
e^{   h ~\hat{r}\cdot  \vec {\sigma}   }= 1\!\!1\cosh h + \sigma_r \sinh h ~.
$$

So you are really dealing with one matrix, $\sigma_r$, with convenient properties.

The [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere) exploits these to the hilt.